# Opposite of where in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of which I would like to remove objects that have specific props. Basically I'm looking for the opposite of `_.where`. For example:

```
var arr = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
var result = _.oppositeOfWhere(arr, {id:2}); // should be [{id:1}, {id:3}]
```

I know this can be done using `_.reject`, but I'm curious if there's a simple way that doesn't require defining a function.

Comment: I think that's the very basic way of doing using `reject`.

Comment: If you switch to [lodash](http://lodash.com/) (which is very similar to underscore) their [`reject`](http://lodash.com/docs#reject) function can do what you want.

Comment: @parchment if you see, underscore `reject` also does it.

Comment: @tzach if you have `primtives` in your array, `without` will work for you, but for array of object it will fail because of references.

Comment: @Mritunjay ah, I thought only lodash does that, but when I tested it, it works. They didn't say that `predicate` can be an object [here](http://underscorejs.org/#reject).

Comment: `reject` doesnt work with objects like `where` does. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/05q1Ltgu/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the edge version of underscore (on github), reject has this behaviour as of [#1582](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/pull/1582). This does essentially the same as below (delegates to matches). This is currently in the controversial 1.7 release (the release may be removed)

```
_.reject(arr, {id: 2}); // => [{id:1}, {id:3}]
```

In previous versions this is possible via matches

```
_.reject(arr, _.matches({id: 2})); // => [{id:1}, {id:3}]
```

Comment: Both of these work in v1.9.0, thanks to the private function [cb](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/cbecaf0377a3fde1e25fdb3d3138b27466bc4eb7/underscore.js#L89): "An internal function to generate callbacks that can be applied to each element in a collection, returning the desired result — either `identity`, an arbitrary callback, a property matcher, or a property accessor."